# IPv6 Address Formatting and Lookup

Tags: ipv6

I'm seeing an IPv6 address that ends in :f68.  Is shorthand for :0f68 or :f680?  I'm trying to do a lookup on it and for some reason doesn't like the 3 digit segment.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`:f68` expands to `:0f68`. The IP address components are hexadecimal *numbers* – only the leading zeros can be omitted. (See RFC 4291 section 2.2, ["Text Representation of Addresses"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.2).)